# Solution for contenteditable="true" property is not working for image tag when resize image in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to resize the image inside the img tag in a div. I am using contenteditable="true" property for the div. I am editing the content but I do not select the image and resize the image in chrome and firefox

my code is simple

div contenteditable="true"
img src="img.png"
div

This code is working in the IE browser and I am selecting an image and also resize the image but in chrome and firefox, it won't work for me.

Please give some solution. Thank you

Comment: U need to use CSS. For the div, Set overflow: initial; and resize: both;

Comment: Using above CSS but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following CSS to your div. (if that doesn't work, try applying it to the image)

```
div{
overflow: auto;
resize: both;
}
```

Check the CSS of 'img' div in following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4ntjsv5/

Comment: Can u provide a reproducible example? Like on JSFiddle